# CSharpCompilation emit fails when referencing a .dll not part of the project

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn-code-analysis

### Background:

I have a c# file 'code.txt' which needs to be compiled and executed.
This file requires the CsvHelper package from nuget in order to be.

I have two projects which are identical with the exception of one has the CsvHelper nuget package installed and other does not.

### Problem:

1. If I have the CsvHelper nuget package installed on the running
   project, then the compiled code executes successfully.
2. However, if I do not install the nuget package into the project but manually
   reference the required and dependent .dlls, it compiles but fails to
   run with the following exception

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CsvHelper, Version=30.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

### CSharpCompilation Code without installed Nuget:

```
MetadataReference[] References = new MetadataReference[]
        {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Uri).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Data.DataRow).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Data.DataRowComparer).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Net.Http.HttpClient).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Numerics.BigInteger).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Button).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Xml.XmlAttribute).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Xml.Linq.XDocument).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\CsvHelper.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\System.Buffers.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\System.Memory.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll")),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\DLL's\System.ValueTuple.dll"))
        };

        string code = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\Code.txt"));
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
        Compilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            Path.GetRandomFileName(),
            new[] { syntaxTree },
            References,
            new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary, optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Debug
            ));

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                    diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                    diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());

                Type type = assembly.GetType("NSImport.ImportTesting");
                object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                type.InvokeMember("FuncMain",
                    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    obj,
                    new object[] { });
            }
        }
```

### Code.txt

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper;

namespace NSImport
{
    internal class ImportTesting
    {
        public void FuncMain()
        {
            string filename = GetInputFileName();

            var configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                Delimiter = ",",
                HasHeaderRecord = true, //default value in any case
                Quote = '"'             //default value in any case
            };
        }

        private string GetInputFileName()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
                Title = "Select input file",
                DefaultExt = "csv",
                Filter = "CSV File (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*",
                FilterIndex = 1,
                CheckFileExists = true,
                CheckPathExists = true,
                Multiselect = false
            };

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                return ofd.FileName;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

### Questions:

1. I came across some comments stating the .dlls need to be a part of
   the running application. What I would like to know is why is this
   the case?
2. Is there a way to have the code executing with the referenced .dlls not being apart of the project?
3. What is the best way to chase down FileNotFoundException since the exception is pretty vague?

Any pointers or assistance would be highly appreciated.